# proof of a series

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Hi cant figure out how to prove the following:

given $$
f(x)=(x-b)^5+(x-a)^4
$$
prove that the point $f'(c)=0$ divides the segment $[a,b]$ to a ratio of $4:5$

hint: use Rolle's theorm

Comment: The given function as-it-is doesn't pass the hypothesis of Rolle's theorem. Could you double check for possible typoes ?

Comment: It strikes me what was meant is likely $f(x) = (x - b)^5(x - a)^4$ which if I'm not mistaken *does* satisfy the hypothesis of Rolle's.  And thins work out.  Cheers.

Comment: @Robert Lewis: Got the same if $f(x) = {(x - b)^5}{(x - a)^4}$
\begin{array}{l}
f'(x) = (5a + 4b - 9x){(b - x)^4}{(a - x)^3}\\
5a + 4b - 9x = 0\\
x = \frac{{5a + 4b}}{9} = \frac{5}{9}a + \frac{4}{9}b
\end{array}

Comment: Why not post it as an answer?